# What have i missed that i need to run Redshift Plasmoid?

Tags: software-installation, kde, plasma

I've installed [Redshift](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Redshift+Plasmoid?content=148737) through synaptic, adding the ppa as [described](https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-team/+archive/ubuntu/kxstudio). I've built the KDE itself and installed Eclipse (including the cdt). Yet, nothing happens when I run redshiftautostart as instructed.

Comment: I needed the plasma desktop itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install the plasma desktop itself. I'm still having problems with using the task-bar icon to toggle it on and off, but theankfully the desktop plasmoid does work as a toggle.